# Can not borrow mutable more than once at a time error when calling function in loop in Rust

Tags: rust, borrow-checker

I am trying to use a function that I made in rust to propose a series of choices for a user to select from and then execute an associated function from that choice. However, it is giving me a compiler error when I use it in a loop. I'm not sure why because the return value of the function is not linked to the lifetime of the reference I feel like it should be self contained. Can somebody help me refactor this.

The error that I get is

```
  --> src\ui\song_editor_cli.rs:15:66
   |
15 |         if let Some(res) = choice_ui::ui_offer_choices(&choices, editor) {
   |                                                        --------  ^^^^^^ `*editor` was mutably borrowed here in the previous iteration of the loop
   |                                                        |
   |                                                        first borrow used here, in later iteration of loop
```

my code is

```rust
pub fn ui(editor: &mut SongEditor) {
    let choices = vec![
        Choice::new("Load Song".to_string(), Box::from(load_ui)),
        Choice::new("Create Song".to_string(), Box::from(create_ui)),
        Choice::new("Edit Song".to_string(), Box::from(edit_ui)),
    ];
    println!("Hello! Welcome to Song Maker!");
    loop {
        if let Some(res) = choice_ui::ui_offer_choices(&choices, editor) {
            if let Err(err) = res {
                println!("{err}");
            }
        }
        else {
            break
        }
    }
    println!("Goodbye from Song Maker!")
}
```

```rust
pub struct Choice<Args, Res> {
    prompt: String,
    callback: Box<dyn Fn(Args) -> Res>
}

impl<Args, Res> Choice<Args, Res> {
    pub fn new(prompt: String, callback: Box<dyn Fn(Args) -> Res>) -> Self {
        Choice {prompt, callback}
    }
    
    pub fn call(&self, args: Args) -> Res {
        (self.callback)(args)
    }
}
pub fn ui_offer_choices<Args, Res>(choices: &Vec<Choice<Args, Res>>, args: Args) -> Option<Res> {
    for (index, choice) in choices.iter().enumerate() {
        println!("\t{}. {}", index + 1, choice.prompt)
    }
    println!("\tq. Quit");
    let mut buf = String::new();
    loop {
        buf.clear();
        io::stdin().read_line(&mut buf).expect("Failed to read user input!");
        let buf = buf.trim();
        if buf == "q" {
            return None;
        }
        let choice_number = buf.parse::<usize>().expect("failed to parse user input as number!") - 1;
        if choice_number < choices.len() {
            return Some(choices[choice_number].call(args));
        }
        else {
            println!("{} was not recognized as an available option! Try again or press 'q' to quit!", choice_number)
        }
    }
}
```

load_ui, create_ui, and edit_ui all have a signature like fn func_name(editor &mut SongEditor) -> Result<(), &'static str>

I have tried making the ui fn take a owned mutable SongEditor and mutably borrow it each time in the loop but that did not work. I feel like I can try changing my ui fns signature to take a Rc but I feel like I have some sort of fundamental misunderstanding of how I should be designing this and where my issue lies. In similar problems that I have seen on stack overflow there is typically a return value with a lifetime tied to the borrowed value. I do not think that that exists in my use case as my only returned lifetime is static.

Comment: Reproducible code on the playground: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=2361f3ca5bbb22a3b071b6ba6ea36c0a

Comment: In the minimal example, if you change the second argument to `ui_offer_choices()` from the generic `Args` to the concrete `&mut SongEditor`, it compiles. (Never mind atm that it doesn't fit the intended body of the function, this is just about the signature.) It seems like using the generic `Args` somehow tied the lifetime of the `&mut SongEditor` reference to the lifetime of the `choices` argument.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think you can make this work as-is. `Args` can only be deduced to a singular type which for mutable references will include the lifetime. So you have `choices` with a singular lifetime for the parameter its expecting which must be the same as `editor`. Thus in your loop you call `ui_offer_choices` the same lifetime each time, which is not allowed.

You probably need to change `Choice` to use `dyn Fn(&mut Args) -> Res` instead so that the lifetime can be deferred until the call-site. So change all `Args` to `&mut Args` like shown [here on the playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=cd69395e194ef20d08eeb44570eb4017).

Comment: Hey, thank you so much this fix works great for my use case and I found your description of the problem very illuminating. Though I wish there was a way to make my choices api work for both referenced parameters and owned parameters. I will leave the thread open in case I can get some insight on that idea or how people would approach solving a similar problem.

Comment: Could you perhaps explain why the code in the question is rejected by the borrow checker? I.e. if the code were accepted, how could incorrect safe code be written? I'm asking because it's not entirely obvious to me... e.g. would it be possible to store something from `choices` into `&mut SongEditor`, and somehow invalidate it later?

Comment: @user4815162342 [Here is a much simplified version](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=5003b3584d3b50c99c8ee466d0365367) that shows how you would be able to use that kind of signature to get multiple mutable references to the same value, which Rust rejects. Its not really about "invalidating" it since multiple mutable references to the same value is immediate undefined behavior; any number of things could be written to go wrong in safe code since Rust will work under the assumption that mutable references can't be mutated or even read from other places.

Comment: @kmdreko Thanks for the example. I understand mutable aliasing being UB; I was referring to non-aliasing-related lifetime bugs prevented by the borrow checker. One difference is that `choices` isn't mut in the OP's code, so I'm not sure if this issue applies there.

Comment: @user4815162342 not being `mut` is a moot point since interior mutability exists

Comment: @user4815162342 *"I was referring to non-aliasing-related lifetime bugs prevented by the borrow checker"* - I'm not sure how to respond to that since the borrow checker is only concerned with lifetimes and aliasing-related issues are the only things being checked.

Comment: @kmdreko We probably have some sort of misunderstanding. Surely you'd agree borrow checker checks things other than aliasing, such as not allowing a (live) reference to outlive the referred-to value, or data escaping a closure, or data flowing from one reference to the other, to name just some. But that's a digression - I think your point that interior mutability exists is sufficient to answer my question.